# Error in Toft(c(28, 5, 7)) : argument "A" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I have to create a function that estimates hourly temperature (T) for any time of day.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(foreach)
library(knitr)
library(gridExtra)
```

Heres the formula I am trying to create a function for

T(t) = Ta + Asin[(w(t - to))]

Here is the function that I have

```
Toft <- function(Ta, A, t){
  (Ta + (sin(A)))*((2*pi/24)*(t - 8))
}
Toft(c(28, 5, 7))
```

Error in Toft(c(28, 5, 7)) : argument "A" is missing, with no default

I get this error

Comment: Just do Toft(28,5,7)

Comment: @ChristianSkjøth Thank you !